# Auto width button-group within table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following table:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>mk-567</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, col4 has way to much width, I tried to set `width:auto` but it does not work and if I manually set the width, when I change my page resolution it looks bad, really bad. I tried to set to `width: 1px` but the buttons do not wrap each other.

There is a way to "auto width" the column to the buttons?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue is. What do you mean by _"col4 has way to much width"_? Do you want the button group to expand to fill the container?

Comment: @j08691 Oops auto correct. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @j08691 I need the column to adjust to the buttons total width, if F.E. the two buttons are in total 100px, I need the column to adjust to that width. Like I said I tried to set the width manually but that ruins the web desing when the resolution es changed

Answer (score 0):

You dont need use "button-group" in table. Table is already working on row-col system. Just put buttons in same row.

```css
.container {
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}

h4 {
  margin: 2rem 0rem 1rem;
}

.table-image {
  td,
  th {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Day</th>
            <th scope="col">Article Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Author</th>
            <th scope="col">Shares</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Bootstrap 4 CDN and Starter Template</td>
            <td>Cristina</td>
            <td>2.846</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Bootstrap Grid 4 Tutorial and Examples</td>
            <td>Cristina</td>
            <td>3.417</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Bootstrap Flexbox Tutorial and Examples</td>
            <td>Cristina</td>
            <td>1.234</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
```